# Pass ImageView from one activity to another - Intent - Android

Tags: android, android-intent

I have 170 images in the drawable folder in my android app. I have one activity displaying all of them. What is want to do is to pass the clicked imageview to another activity (Zoom_activity) where the user can zoom it and play around with it. How do I achieve it?

All the images are 500x500px. So I can't think of decoding them into Bitmaps and passing Btmaps via Intent. Please suggest a better and simple way to do it! I have already had a look at the other answers here on SO but none of them solved my problem.

Here is my code:

Activity_1.java

```
Intent startzoomactivity = new Intent(Activity_one.this, Zoom_Image.class);
String img_name = name.getText().toString().toLowerCase(); //name is a textview which is in refrence to the imageview.
startzoomactivity.putExtra("getimage", img_name);
startActivity(startzoomactivity);
```

Zoom_Activity.java

```
    Intent startzoomactivity = getIntent();
    String img_res = getIntent().getStringExtra("getimage");
    String img_fin = "R.drawable."+img_res;
    img.setImageResource(Integer.parseInt(img_fin));
```

Error: App force closes

Please help me solve this problem!
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Integer.parseInt()` only works for strings like "1" or "123" that really contain just the string representation of an Integer.

What you need is find a drawable resource by its name.

This can be done using reflection:

```
String name = "image_0";
final Field field = R.drawable.getField(name);
int id = field.getInt(null);
Drawable drawable = getResources().getDrawable(id);
```

Or using `Resources.getIdentifier()`:

```
String name = "image_0";
int id = getResources().getIdentifier(name, "drawable", getPackageName());
Drawable drawable = getResources().getDrawable(id);
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying is wrong. You can not convert `"R.drawable.name"` with `Integer.parseInt`.  Integer.parseInt is expecting something like `"100"`. You should use

```
getIdentifier(img_fin, "drawable", getPackageName());
```

to retrieve the resources id you are looking for

Answer (score 0):

Use `getResources().getIdentifier` to load image from Drawable in ImageView as:

```
int img_id = getResources().getIdentifier(img_res, "drawable", getPackageName());
img.setImageResource(img_id);
```